# R data.table, keys can't fit in memory?

Tags: r, memory-management, data.table

I imported a huge text file using data.table in hopes of being able to work with it because data.table saves me from needing to lead the entire (40Gb) file into memory. Although I was able to import using fread, the setkey command did not work due to running out of memory.

```
setwd("K:/")
library(data.table)
df <- fread("prepared_file.txt")
dflist <- unique(df$V1)
```

works fine, producing the expected list of 2874 items of 18 characters each, but:

```
setkey(df, V1)
```

gives me:

```
Warning messages:
1: In forderv(x, cols, sort = TRUE, retGrp = FALSE) :
Reached total allocation of 32587Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In forderv(x, cols, sort = TRUE, retGrp = FALSE) :
Reached total allocation of 32587Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I take this to mean that they list of keys itself did not fit in memory.
Is there anything else I can do to make this work with the data.table package? And if I use other options such as rmysql or hdf5 format, can I expect the same problem as I will still have the same large number of keys?

Comment: Can you double check that V1 is a factor? If it's not, that will _greatly_ reduce its space requirements (`df$V1 <- as.factor(df$V1)`)
Also, 64GB of RAM might be worth looking into ;)

Comment: I had not done that, but I don't seem to have enough to change to a factor either:
`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.3 Gb`

Comment: If you did `gc()` and it still doesn't want to allocate, you might need to chunk your data, transforming each chunk individually (to have a factor) and combining the results. These results should need much less memory (roughly 19 - 4 = 15 bytes saved per row)

Comment: If you are already running out of memory on this operation, subsequent operations may also be problematic as R in general is not memory efficient and easily creates copies of objects. With hdf5, you wouldn't have this issue - as you wouldn't be able to set a key. Of course, this means that you can't treat it easily like a data table, but instead have to know which rows you want to access. In the end - I think the solution will depend on what you want to do with it.

Comment: @AlexR I thought gc() was something you ran before or after a command to make sure that any unneeded files were clear from memory, but I tried running `gc(eqtl$V1 <- as.factor(eqtl$V1))` and it gave me no errors except for the memory error I had previously.
@HolgerHoefling, I will be accessing rows based on the content of up to three columns, which is why I thought that a key-based approach would be correct.
My final goal is to do statistics on subsets of the data (primarily using the aggregate function) that are based on the three columns.

Comment: @JamesHanks gc() "garbage collection" is a call to tell R to clean up after itself. Sometimes it causes memory to be freed just enough to prevent an OOM in a subsequent operation. The Package ff might be something worth trying - there is a github package ffbase2 (seems inactive, though), wich allows dplyr to work with it and it keeps the data on disk, saving lots of memory trading it in for lots of IO.

Comment: What version are you using? 1.9.7 had improvements to setkey recently for bigger datasets. Also use `:=` for instead of `$<-` for memory efficiency.

Comment: I am using 1.9.6, I will try 1.9.7, thanks for the tips! @jangorecki